# Python и парсинг URL

Tags: python, url, синтаксический-анализ

Как на питоне распарсить строку вида
 `fragment=u'access_token=e5e5ee05b656b9cde67dee0cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX50684d5c26c2bff82e992b&expires_in=8XX00&user_id=6340XXX')`

которую получил уже после urlparse()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[urlparse.parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)?